# How can I remove the white space under my footer

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to remove the white space under the footer on this site - http://binarydefense.cle.digital

Any help would be appreciated! I tried margins, padding, heights.. Nothing seems to be working for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a minimum, complete, verifiable example into the body of your question - links to external sites may go away in the future and eliminate the value of your question for future users of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You have a margin-bottom in `hentry` class, in `article` tag,
try this code:

```
.hentry {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the wrapper `div`s encapsulating your footer logo has the `.wpb_content_element` class applied to it with a `margin-bottom` of `35px` which is increasing the height of your container elements.

Either override this style using a higher-priority selector or modify the culprit stylesheet (`js_composer.min.css`) to your liking.